# Css pseudo elment :before effecting :first-of-type:first-letter

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a strange problem with css pseudo elements. I tried to design an initial for my paragraph elements. I did this with the :first-of-type pseudo elment. It all woeked well. Then I wanted to add an info box to the right of the text. I used the pseudo element :before for it. When I did this, the initial changed it's height to the height of the before elment.
I set up an fiddle to show my code:

```css
div.project-vorsch p:first-of-type:first-letter {
  font-size: 500%;
  line-height: 1;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#facts {
  clear: both;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  line-height: 1.61111;
  float: right;
  width: 32%;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.project_content:before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-vorsch">
  <div class="project_content">
    <div id="facts">
      <strong>Format:</strong>
      <br>
      <strong>Dauer:</strong>
    </div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt leo vel tellus efficitur luctus. Ut elementum semper sodales. Vivamus dictum pellentesque tortor a pellentesque. Aliquam venenatis quam sed sagittis ultricies. Pellentesque
      accumsan ipsum sapien, in tincidunt lacus finibus eget. Phasellus pellentesque lectus eget quam pulvinar pharetra. Vestibulum varius ante at tellus tincidunt rutrum. Morbi a euismod erat. Aliquam hendrerit diam quis felis fermentum, egestas suscipit
      quam dictum. Vivamus efficitur, odio porta tincidunt vestibulum, sapien nunc aliquam ligula, at imperdiet felis ex sit amet tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt leo vel tellus efficitur luctus. Ut elementum
      semper sodales. Vivamus dictum pellentesque tortor a pellentesque. Aliquam venenatis quam sed sagittis ultricies. Pellentesque accumsan ipsum sapien, in tincidunt lacus finibus eget. Phasellus pellentesque lectus eget quam pulvinar pharetra. Vestibulum
      varius ante at tellus tincidunt rutrum. Morbi a euismod erat. Aliquam hendrerit diam quis felis fermentum, egestas suscipit quam dictum. Vivamus efficitur, odio porta tincidunt vestibulum, sapien nunc aliquam ligula, at imperdiet felis ex sit amet
      tortor. Quisque quis erat nibh. Morbi enim est, rutrum eu tempor sodales, vulputate at dui. Praesent consequat tortor pharetra tellus pharetra, vel pulvinar mi lobortis. Cras ac ante feugiat, ornare eros in, ornare erat. Phasellus arcu nisl, vulputate
      ac fringilla in, vehicula in mi. Nam feugiat ex non dui tincidunt, nec faucibus ante tincidunt. Mauris nunc leo, varius eget consectetur at, egestas ut nunc. Proin rhoncus orci sed rutrum placerat. Vivamus nibh risus, accumsan vitae nulla eget,
      hendrerit consectetur justo. Pellentesque posuere, neque nec rhoncus finibus, leo augue mattis est, vitae elementum dolor dolor non risus. Nam mollis luctus ligula sit amet viverra. Donec accumsan, tortor vehicula dignissim convallis, elit arcu
      tincidunt orci, ut condimentum lorem neque sit amet lacus. Nullam ornare, arcu non tempor elementum, nibh urna tristique ex, rutrum dignissim ipsum nibh sit amet mi. Duis auctor eleifend neque quis eleifend. Aliquam augue ipsum, sodales quis consequat
      et, lacinia eget dolor. Mauris tempor, diam eu pretium tincidunt, diam lorem auctor sapien, et pretium orci quam vel ex. Donec lobortis ipsum at ante elementum, vitae accumsan nunc mattis. Curabitur non volutpat velit. Etiam rhoncus ut justo non
      feugiat. Aenean mollis, nibh at interdum placerat, sapien augue viverra massa, sed rhoncus nisl ligula non ante. In eu ipsum mauris. Duis interdum nec turpis a vulputate. Mauris mattis arcu ac augue pharetra vestibulum. Curabitur nisl ante, lobortis
      fermentum ex vitae, luctus placerat enim. Sed et sem justo. Proin orci lectus, gravida et neque eget, bibendum commodo quam. Curabitur ut lobortis lacus, non dignissim tortor. In ut elit ex. Sed imperdiet faucibus neque, nec facilisis nulla interdum
      non. Nam tempus arcu ex, ac varius libero iaculis et. Quisque non diam nec leo maximus condimentum. Curabitur lacinia neque eu egestas dapibus. Phasellus luctus ipsum odio, ac placerat tortor dictum pharetra. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome? #facts div and paragraph being side by side?

Comment: why the :before element ? it's useless in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `height` in `div.project_content:before` affects **both** `#facts` and `p`.

If you want to offset the right-hand box and leave a gap in the text above it, instead use 
 `margin-top: 200px` on `#facts`:

```css
div.project-vorsch p:first-of-type:first-letter {
  font-size: 500%;
  line-height: 1;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#facts {
  clear: both;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  line-height: 1.61111;
  float: right;
  width: 32%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-vorsch">
  <div class="project_content">
    <div id="facts">
      <strong>Format:</strong>
      <br>
      <strong>Dauer:</strong>
    </div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt leo vel tellus efficitur luctus. Ut elementum semper sodales. Vivamus dictum pellentesque tortor a pellentesque. Aliquam venenatis quam sed sagittis ultricies. Pellentesque
      accumsan ipsum sapien, in tincidunt lacus finibus eget. Phasellus pellentesque lectus eget quam pulvinar pharetra. Vestibulum varius ante at tellus tincidunt rutrum. Morbi a euismod erat. Aliquam hendrerit diam quis felis fermentum, egestas suscipit
      quam dictum. Vivamus efficitur, odio porta tincidunt vestibulum, sapien nunc aliquam ligula, at imperdiet felis ex sit amet tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt leo vel tellus efficitur luctus. Ut elementum
      semper sodales. Vivamus dictum pellentesque tortor a pellentesque. Aliquam venenatis quam sed sagittis ultricies. Pellentesque accumsan ipsum sapien, in tincidunt lacus finibus eget. Phasellus pellentesque lectus eget quam pulvinar pharetra. Vestibulum
      varius ante at tellus tincidunt rutrum. Morbi a euismod erat. Aliquam hendrerit diam quis felis fermentum, egestas suscipit quam dictum. Vivamus efficitur, odio porta tincidunt vestibulum, sapien nunc aliquam ligula, at imperdiet felis ex sit amet
      tortor. Quisque quis erat nibh. Morbi enim est, rutrum eu tempor sodales, vulputate at dui. Praesent consequat tortor pharetra tellus pharetra, vel pulvinar mi lobortis. Cras ac ante feugiat, ornare eros in, ornare erat. Phasellus arcu nisl, vulputate
      ac fringilla in, vehicula in mi. Nam feugiat ex non dui tincidunt, nec faucibus ante tincidunt. Mauris nunc leo, varius eget consectetur at, egestas ut nunc. Proin rhoncus orci sed rutrum placerat. Vivamus nibh risus, accumsan vitae nulla eget,
      hendrerit consectetur justo. Pellentesque posuere, neque nec rhoncus finibus, leo augue mattis est, vitae elementum dolor dolor non risus. Nam mollis luctus ligula sit amet viverra. Donec accumsan, tortor vehicula dignissim convallis, elit arcu
      tincidunt orci, ut condimentum lorem neque sit amet lacus. Nullam ornare, arcu non tempor elementum, nibh urna tristique ex, rutrum dignissim ipsum nibh sit amet mi. Duis auctor eleifend neque quis eleifend. Aliquam augue ipsum, sodales quis consequat
      et, lacinia eget dolor. Mauris tempor, diam eu pretium tincidunt, diam lorem auctor sapien, et pretium orci quam vel ex. Donec lobortis ipsum at ante elementum, vitae accumsan nunc mattis. Curabitur non volutpat velit. Etiam rhoncus ut justo non
      feugiat. Aenean mollis, nibh at interdum placerat, sapien augue viverra massa, sed rhoncus nisl ligula non ante. In eu ipsum mauris. Duis interdum nec turpis a vulputate. Mauris mattis arcu ac augue pharetra vestibulum. Curabitur nisl ante, lobortis
      fermentum ex vitae, luctus placerat enim. Sed et sem justo. Proin orci lectus, gravida et neque eget, bibendum commodo quam. Curabitur ut lobortis lacus, non dignissim tortor. In ut elit ex. Sed imperdiet faucibus neque, nec facilisis nulla interdum
      non. Nam tempus arcu ex, ac varius libero iaculis et. Quisque non diam nec leo maximus condimentum. Curabitur lacinia neque eu egestas dapibus. Phasellus luctus ipsum odio, ac placerat tortor dictum pharetra. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If instead you want the text to wrap around the `#facts` element, I'd recommend simply moving the `#facts` `<div>` to sit in the HTML structure where you want it to appear:

```css
div.project-vorsch p:first-of-type:first-letter {
  font-size: 500%;
  line-height: 1;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#facts {
  clear: both;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  line-height: 1.61111;
  float: right;
  width: 32%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-vorsch">
  <div class="project_content">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt leo vel tellus efficitur luctus. Ut elementum semper sodales. Vivamus dictum pellentesque tortor a pellentesque. Aliquam venenatis quam sed sagittis ultricies. Pellentesque
      accumsan ipsum sapien, in tincidunt lacus finibus eget. Phasellus pellentesque lectus eget quam pulvinar pharetra. Vestibulum varius ante at tellus tincidunt rutrum. Morbi a euismod erat. Aliquam hendrerit diam quis felis fermentum, egestas suscipit
      quam dictum. Vivamus efficitur, odio porta tincidunt vestibulum, sapien nunc aliquam ligula, at imperdiet felis ex sit amet tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tincidunt leo vel tellus efficitur luctus. Ut elementum semper sodales. 
      
      <div id="facts">
        <strong>Format:</strong>
        <br>
        <strong>Dauer:</strong>
      </div>
      
      Vivamus dictum pellentesque tortor a pellentesque. Aliquam venenatis quam sed sagittis ultricies. Pellentesque accumsan ipsum sapien, in tincidunt lacus finibus eget. Phasellus pellentesque lectus eget quam pulvinar pharetra. Vestibulum
      varius ante at tellus tincidunt rutrum. Morbi a euismod erat. Aliquam hendrerit diam quis felis fermentum, egestas suscipit quam dictum. Vivamus efficitur, odio porta tincidunt vestibulum, sapien nunc aliquam ligula, at imperdiet felis ex sit amet
      tortor. Quisque quis erat nibh. Morbi enim est, rutrum eu tempor sodales, vulputate at dui. Praesent consequat tortor pharetra tellus pharetra, vel pulvinar mi lobortis. Cras ac ante feugiat, ornare eros in, ornare erat. Phasellus arcu nisl, vulputate
      ac fringilla in, vehicula in mi. Nam feugiat ex non dui tincidunt, nec faucibus ante tincidunt. Mauris nunc leo, varius eget consectetur at, egestas ut nunc. Proin rhoncus orci sed rutrum placerat. Vivamus nibh risus, accumsan vitae nulla eget,
      hendrerit consectetur justo. Pellentesque posuere, neque nec rhoncus finibus, leo augue mattis est, vitae elementum dolor dolor non risus. Nam mollis luctus ligula sit amet viverra. Donec accumsan, tortor vehicula dignissim convallis, elit arcu
      tincidunt orci, ut condimentum lorem neque sit amet lacus. Nullam ornare, arcu non tempor elementum, nibh urna tristique ex, rutrum dignissim ipsum nibh sit amet mi. Duis auctor eleifend neque quis eleifend. Aliquam augue ipsum, sodales quis consequat
      et, lacinia eget dolor. Mauris tempor, diam eu pretium tincidunt, diam lorem auctor sapien, et pretium orci quam vel ex. Donec lobortis ipsum at ante elementum, vitae accumsan nunc mattis. Curabitur non volutpat velit. Etiam rhoncus ut justo non
      feugiat. Aenean mollis, nibh at interdum placerat, sapien augue viverra massa, sed rhoncus nisl ligula non ante. In eu ipsum mauris. Duis interdum nec turpis a vulputate. Mauris mattis arcu ac augue pharetra vestibulum. Curabitur nisl ante, lobortis
      fermentum ex vitae, luctus placerat enim. Sed et sem justo. Proin orci lectus, gravida et neque eget, bibendum commodo quam. Curabitur ut lobortis lacus, non dignissim tortor. In ut elit ex. Sed imperdiet faucibus neque, nec facilisis nulla interdum
      non. Nam tempus arcu ex, ac varius libero iaculis et. Quisque non diam nec leo maximus condimentum. Curabitur lacinia neque eu egestas dapibus. Phasellus luctus ipsum odio, ac placerat tortor dictum pharetra. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The problem that I am trying to wrap my head around is, why is it happening? Feature bug?

Comment: Not a bug. It's because the pseudo-element essentially gets 'injected' at `x` position in the DOM. In this case, it gets injected **`:before`** `.project_content`. You now have three elements that are a child of `.project-vorsch`, and are applying a height to the first one (the `:before`). Considering you're floating both the `:before` and the other two elements, they take the `height` of `:before` into consideration for their offset.

Comment: So it's not possible to apply the height of the :before just to the #facts <div> and not to the initial. I can't move the #facts inside the html structure because the content of the paragraph is loaded dynamically.

Comment: I used the :before element so the code wraps around the #fact div. If I use margin-top the code will not wrap around and I can't place the element where it should appear because the content of the paragraph is loaded dynamically.

Comment: Hmm. The only other solution I can think of is to use absolute positioning (`position: absolute` with `top: 200px` and `right: 0`) on `#fact`, though that would overlap the content.